# iOS10 trying to access local intranet server via IP but keeps changing URL to localhost:3000//

Tags: ios, macos, localhost

I am running my development server on my Macbook Pro running Mac OSX 10.11

Accessing the webapp from the Macbook Pro itself via localhost:3000 works fine.

Now I want to access the webapp from my phone. Both devices are connected to the same wifi network.

The local IP of my macbook pro is 10.0.1.7.

I open safari or chrome on my iOS device and type in `http://10.0.1.7:3000` and the browser instantly turns the URL into `localhost:3000//`

Whats going on? Why is it doing this?

I remember sometime ago this use to work, but maybe with a recent iOS update it stopped working.

I have even tried to use the network name of my computer

`My-Macbook-Pro.local:3000` and it still resolves to localhost:3000//

Comment: Are you sure it's not redirecting you to that address?  Your iPhone would not be changing an IP to localhost just because of the port number.

Comment: why would it redirect me? The url I type in the address bar is the local IP of my Macbook Pro `http://10.0.1.7:3000`. But when I press enter it just goes to `localhost:3000//`

Comment: The web server you're running on the MBP must have a setting somewhere that is redirecting requests to "localhost".  That is the only explanation I can think of that's even possible.

Comment: Try going to that IP from another computer and I bet it will do the same thing

Comment: From some computer on the local network, try running `curl -I http://10.0.1.7:3000` -- my guess is that you'll get back something that starts with a 301 or 302 status (e.g. "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently") and includes "Location: http://localhost:3000/" -- that's the server telling the client to go to that location, *not* something triggered from the client.